# Can i use TypeScript 2.0.6 with VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Can i use TypeScript 2.0.6 with Visual Studio 2017?

or only can i use > 2.1?

And,

What is diference between Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler and Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild?

And what happen if i have not Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler? It use local compiler?

Thanks!

Comment: I think they're just the same thing packaged differently (or for different build tools). As for using it, you probably need to have the proper service pack installed but you should be able to use any version.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler) is the TypeScript compiler. [Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/) is an MSBuild task that also *includes* the compiler.

You can still target previous versions of TypeScript, as long as you have those SDK's installed as well; however, I would recommend upgrading if you're going to use VS2017 anyway.

Comment: If I have Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild in my project with Nuget, is necesary install Typescript SDK locally?

Comment: It depends on how you want to work. I have TypeScript installed through the Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package, but I also have it installed globally through npm. The reason being that I have projects I develop with Visual Studio and ones that I don't. If you are exclusively using the MS tool chain in VS, then you should be fine with the nuget packages, and VS will build based off the csproj elements. If you're using other tooling (e.g., grunt, gulp), you might want to install the global npm package as well.